# How to remove floating values from a data set in R

Tags: r, dataset

I have a R code to filter the data frame values - age and no. of cars. I want to remove the floating values in car column if there are any.
For example:

```
Age Cars
29  2
27  3
18  2.3
31  4
17  2
20  -1
```

Here I want to remove the records whose age is <18, cars >=0 and also records having 2.3 cars (floating) value in R.

```
bikers_inconsistent <- function(n){
  # To check age of the rider >=18 and no. of cars >=0 
  x <- n[n$age>=18 & n$cars>=0 ,]

 return(x)
}
```

I have written the code to retrieve cars >=0 and age>=18. But struggling to filter the data which have floating values.

Please help as I'm new to R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if a number is an integer by using the modulo operation (`%%`):
If a number modulo 1 is 0, that number is an integer.

```
data <- data.frame(
  age = c(29, 27, 18, 31, 17, 20),
  cars = c(2, 3, 2.3, 4, 2, -1)
)
bikers_inconsistent <- function(n){
  # To check age of the rider >=18 and no. of cars >=0 
  x <- n[n$age>=18 & n$cars>=0 & n$cars %% 1 == 0,]
  
  return(x)
}
bikers_inconsistent(data)

#  age cars
#1  29    2
#2  27    3
#4  31    4
```

Another option would be to check if `n$cars == as.integer(n$cars)`.

Answer (score 1):

Floating values can be tough due to precision issues. I would recommend using a tolerance for how far from an integer a number can be while still counting as an integer. [Have a look at this important FAQ for why a tolerance is needed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518/903061). Here's a simple implementation:

```
is_float = function(x, tolerance = 1e-6) {
  abs(x - round(x)) > tolerance
}


bikers_inconsistent <- function(n){
  # To check age of the rider >=18 and no. of cars >=0 
  x <- n[n$age>=18 & n$cars>=0 & !is_float(n$cars),]
  
  return(x)
}

bikers_inconsistent(data)
#   age cars
# 1  29    2
# 2  27    3
# 4  31    4
```